# How to fix packaging dependency on react-gauge-chart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I am trying to find an packaging issue caused by a package called [react-gauge-chart](https://github.com/Martin36/react-gauge-chart). After **installed**, the error 'module not found' was shown. I was wondering the reason behind this issue.

This issue is happening on both my local as well in [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/m931xo3y).

Here is the error from my local:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/views/home/CorrectiveMaintainanceReport.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-gauge-chart' in '/Users/kongwenyao/Documents/GitLab/wefix/src/views/home'
```

Here is the error from Codesandbox:

```
Error

Could not fetch dependencies, please try again in a couple seconds: Something went wrong while packaging the dependency react-gauge-chart@0.1.2: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/tmp/3739059402/node_modules/react-gauge-chart/dist'
```

My local dependencies in package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.18.0",
        "chart.js": "2.7.3",
        "classnames": "2.2.6",
        "eslint-config-google": "^0.12.0",
        "moment": "2.24.0",
        "node-sass": "4.11.0",
        "nouislider": "13.1.1",
        "react": "16.8.4",
        "react-chartjs-2": "2.7.4",
        "react-copy-to-clipboard": "5.0.1",
        "react-datetime": "2.16.3",
        "react-dom": "16.8.4",
        "react-gauge-chart": "^0.1.2",
        "react-google-maps": "9.4.5",
        "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
        "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
        "reactstrap": "7.1.0"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

it because your package module doesn't have the required package

do install

```
yarn add react-gauge-chart or npm install react-gauge-chart
```

Also make sure it is listed under dependency in package.json

Comment: It was successfully installed, but not detected. Felt more like a bundling/packaging issue from that package.

Comment: import-cost shown 0kb (gzipped) and this issue is happening on both local as well as codesandbox environment, so i am justifying that the issue is derived from that package but uncertain the main cause.

Answer (score 0):

it look like you are missing typed libraries  try running
npm i --save-dev @types/react-gauge-chart